# How to optimize SVG's for web?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, svg, loading

I created a static React website and hosted it on AWS. It has many SVG images but they are of large size e.g. 3.5 MB, 5.8 MB, 13 MB, etc. Hence the images are taking too long to load and website freezes. How can I optimize these SVG images so they can load quickly? Is there any quick way to optimize SVG's ?

Comment: https://github.com/svg/svgo

Comment: Some SVG images are just wrappers for large .png images - if that's the case, then an SVG optimizer won't help you, you'll have to optimize the underlying png (by converting it to a lower res jpg for example).

Comment: Ritik, can you explain what kind of SVG is it?

Answer (score 3):

What Michael said.

Those are unusually large file sizes for an SVG. If those SVGs contain large bitmap images, then you may wish to consider:

- optimising their size (as Michael suggests), or
- converting the images to vector shapes (where appropriate)
- moving the bitmaps out of the SVG and use, for eg., `<img srcset>`

If your SVGs don't contain any bitmaps, and just contain a very large number of vector elements, then start by optimising with SVGO/SVGOMG. If they are still slow, there are other things you can do such as:

- Simplifying the paths so they contain fewer segments (some vector editors can do this)
- Merging paths with the same styling into one, or fewer, paths.